# How to escape PowerShell double quotes from a .bat file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, escaping

I'm trying to replace all double quotes in a file (temp1.txt) with two double quotes using this PowerShell command, run from a bat file in Windows 7:

```
powershell -Command "(gc c:\temp\temp1.txt) -replace '\"', '\"\"' | Out-File -encoding UTF8 c:\temp\temp2.txt"
```

I keep getting the error:

> 'Out-File' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

When I change the command to replace the letter "a" with the letter "b", it works fine like this:

```
powershell -Command "(gc c:\temp\temp1.txt) -replace 'a', 'b' | Out-File -encoding UTF8 c:\temp\temp2.txt"
```

I need to escape the double quote since the entire `powershell -Command` is within a double quoted string. How do you escape the double quote?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hm, here you need to escape the `"` on the command line, inside a double quoted string. From my testing, the only thing that seems to work is quadruple double quotes `""""` inside the quoted parameter:

```psh
powershell.exe -command "echo '""""X""""'"
```

So then your command line should be:

```psh
powershell -Command "(gc c:\temp\temp1.txt) -replace '""""', '""""""""' | Out-File -encoding UTF8 c:\temp\temp2.txt"
```

There is another way to handle this with PowerShell, assuming you don't want to just put these commands in a file and call it that way: use `-EncodedCommand`. This lets you base64 encode your entire command or script and pass it as a single parameter on the command line.

So here's your original command:

```psh
(gc c:\temp\temp1.txt) -replace '"', '""' | Out-File -encoding UTF8 c:\temp\temp2.txt
```

Here's a script to encode it:

```psh
$c = @"
(gc c:\temp\temp1.txt) -replace '"', '""' | Out-File -encoding UTF8 c:\temp\temp2.txt
"@
$b = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($c)
$e = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($b)
```

`$e` now contains:

> KABnAGMAIABjADoAXAB0AGUAbQBwAFwAdABlAG0AcAAxAC4AdAB4AHQAKQAgAC0AcgBlAHAAbABhAGMAZQAgACcAIgAnACwAIAAnACIAIgAnACAAfAAgAE8AdQB0AC0ARgBpAGwAZQAgAC0AZQBuAGMAbwBkAGkAbgBnACAAVQBUAEYAOAAgAGMAOgBcAHQAZQBtAHAAXAB0AGUAbQBwADIALgB0AHgAdAA=

So your new command line can be:

```psh
powershell.exe -encodedCommand KABnAGMAIABjADoAXAB0AGUAbQBwAFwAdABlAG0AcAAxAC4AdAB4AHQAKQAgAC0AcgBlAHAAbABhAGMAZQAgACcAIgAnACwAIAAnACIAIgAnACAAfAAgAE8AdQB0AC0ARgBpAGwAZQAgAC0AZQBuAGMAbwBkAGkAbgBnACAAVQBUAEYAOAAgAGMAOgBcAHQAZQBtAHAAXAB0AGUAbQBwADIALgB0AHgAdAA=
```

There is no need to worry about escaping anything.

Comment: I hate that I only just learned about this. Do you know how much time I've spent double- and quad-escaping quotes and running and re-running batch scripts trying to get everything *just* right?  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's a geeky answer.  Use the ascii code for doublequote instead, which is 34, and avoid quoting issues.  Doublequotes are a special cmd.exe character and so is the pipe.

```
powershell "(gc temp1.txt) -replace [char]34,([char]34+[char]34) | set-content temp1.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

The escape character is grave-accent for PowerShell. Try this instead:

```
powershell -Command "(gc c:\temp\temp1.txt) -replace `", `"`" | Out-File -encoding UTF8 c:\temp\temp2.txt"
```

Comment: @ChrisGciso This won't work because while the backtick is the escape character within powershell, you need to escape the `"` from the command prompt so that it can be passed to powershell.

Comment: @ChrisGciso just checked again. You are right. It works on cygwin shell and other *nix shells. All I had to do was double the double quotes in cmd shell.