# How can you export the Visual Studio Code extension list?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need to send all my installed extensions to my colleagues. How can I export them?

The extension manager seems to do nothing... It won't install any extension.

Comment: You can package an extension pack into a `.vsix file` and distribute this file. How to do this is described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58513266/how-to-install-multiple-extensions-in-vscode-using-command-line/71380592#71380592

Comment: @sharhp That answer is actually much more useful here than on that question (which specifically asks for a cli solution, as your disclaimer admits). Probably worth hitting _edit_ on that one and copy and pasting that text here. It is a useful alternative [if it works; haven't tried yet]. (Actually the answer _is_ 100% on the command line, but isn't batch, which is probably what you & OP had in mind; works perfectly here, though.)

Comment: For a bash solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65963925/7881859.

Answer (score 1047, accepted):

**Automatic**

If you are looking forward to an easy one-stop tool to do it for you, I would suggest you to look into the [**Settings Sync**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync) extension.

It will allow

1. *Export* of your configuration and extensions
2. *Share* it with coworkers and teams. You can update the configuration. Their settings will auto updated.

**Manual**

1. Make sure you have the most current version of Visual Studio Code. If you install via a company portal, you might not have the most current version.
2. On machine A

   Unix:

   ```
   code --list-extensions | xargs -L 1 echo code --install-extension
   ```

   Windows (PowerShell, e. g. using Visual Studio Code's integrated Terminal):

   ```
   code --list-extensions | % { "code --install-extension $_" }
   ```
3. Copy and paste the echo output to machine B

   Sample output

   ```
   code --install-extension Angular.ng-template
   code --install-extension DSKWRK.vscode-generate-getter-setter
   code --install-extension EditorConfig.EditorConfig
   code --install-extension HookyQR.beautify
   ```

Please make sure you have the `code` command line installed. For more information, please visit *[Command Line Interface (CLI)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line)*.

Comment: Can someone provide a Windows friendly version of this command? xargs seems to be unique to UNIX.

Comment: @damanptyltd If you use GitHub, you probably have Git Bash installed on your Windows laptop/pc. You can use Unix/Mac commands in that - that how i got it working

Comment: for anybody who thinks they need a windows version, please note, you are supposed to run this from the vscode command line, you can get it by hitting Ctrl+`, then just paste it in!

Comment: I used the Ctrl+` with  --list-extensions command above to get my settings out of my windows vscode and then used Ctrl+` to paste in the code --install results into my vscode instance on Linux (over RDP). It just worked. Downloaded and installed all of them. Awesome

Comment: I'd also appreciate a windows-friendly non-xargs version of this I'm stuck on a PC without admin rights, and they haven't set up bash on these machines :/

Comment: On Mac OSX I had to use the exact `code` executable location: `/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code` ~ I have now just created an alias to it in my `.bash_profile` on all my Mac's

Comment: This should work under Windows PowerShell: `code --list-extensions | % { "code --install-extension $_" }` (I also edited this into the answer)

Comment: @nicc777 Follow Benny's link to how to set up the command-line.  Short answer: open command palette in Code and type "shell command" and there will be a command to add "code" to path.

Comment: copy to `install.sh`, in git bash `start install.sh`

Comment: You can pipe the output to a file so you don't have to copy from the terminal like: `code --list-extensions | xargs -L 1 echo code --install-extension > vsc-extensions.txt`

Comment: What is about [Settings Sync from MS](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync)

Comment: @Jared on Windows it is ctrl + **ö**, german.. to all: **code ...** in terminal opens a new editor with the welcome. But does not print the extensions to the terminal.

Comment: I am on windows 10`powershell 5` and `code -h` or any other parameter opens a new instance but not prints the result to stdout. Should I ask a new question?

Comment: Pure batch file: `@for /f %%l in ('code --list-extensions') do @echo code --install-extension %%l`

Or on command-line (replacing `%%` by `%`): `@for /f %l in ('code --list-extensions') do @echo code --install-extension %l`

Comment: From a Windows batch `.bat`/`.cmd` file: `PowerShell -Command "code --list-extensions | % { """""code --install-extension $_""""" }"` (quote escaping explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575784/how-to-escape-powershell-double-quotes-from-a-bat-file/31575981#31575981)

Comment: If you are on Windows, type `code.cmd --list-extensions` instead of just `code`. The problem is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code` (or vscode install folder) has `code.exe` which opens vscode and is getting called. You actually need to run `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd`, which is the command line utility script.

Comment: @Benny Could you update your answer to show the instructions for Windows users to type `code.cmd` instead of just `code`?

Comment: share as links: `code --list-extensions | xargs -L 1 echo https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=`

Comment: To get `code` to work, type cmd + shift + p in VSCode and look for `Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH`

Comment: If you have the old `extensions` directory files & folders, but don't have access to the old OS you copied them from (and so can't run `code --list-extensions`  to get the list to pass to `code --install-extensions`, here is a way to reformat the directory names (removing the version part) and reinstall them: `for EXT in $( ls ~/old/.vscode/extensions/ ); do NAME=$( echo $EXT | perl -ne 's/\-[\d\.]+$//; print "$_"' ); code --install-extension $NAME; done`

Comment: @adam.hendry why do we need to use code.cmd ?  code already works

Comment: @Cemstrian The problem is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code` (or vscode install folder) has `code.exe` which opens `vscode` and is getting called. You actually need to run `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd`, which is the command line utility script.

Comment: @adam.hendry thanks but it does not open vscode in my computer. I run windows 11. what is your os version?

Comment: @Cemstrian I run Windows 10 and this was over a year ago. I no longer use Settings Sync. I use profiles. Please see my answer below and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76871908/8748308).

Comment: The Settings Sync link is depreciated, see [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync) instead.

Answer (score 272):

I've needed to do this myself a few times - especially when installing on another machine.

*[Common questions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_common-questions)* will give you the location of your folder

> Visual Studio Code looks for extensions under your extensions folder .vscode/extensions. Depending on your platform it is located:

```
Windows %USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions
Mac ~/.vscode/extensions
Linux ~/.vscode/extensions
```

That should show you a list of the extensions.

I've also had success using [Visual Studio Code Settings Sync Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync) to sync settings to GitHub gist.

In the latest release of Visual Studio Code (May 2016), it is now possible to list the installed extensions on the command line:

```
code --list-extensions
```

Comment: For me (linux, code Version 1.7.1) it does not work... it just starts VS Code.

Comment: @vanthome I never tried on Linux but I think this is the same: I first had the same issue you had, until I realized the command line utility is in fact under the `bin` folder of the application installation. If you look at its content you will see it calls the main executable but telling it to execute the CLI instead.

Comment: FYI you'll need to run 'Shell command: Install 'code' command in PATH' from the command palette (cmd/ctrl-shift-p) within VS Code and then run the above code in your terminal to allow this to work.

Comment: @vanthome, on windows, find the **code.cmd** file and try it with this. Worked for me. On **wsl, Debian**, I get with code.cmd: `/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code.cmd: 1: /mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code.cmd: @echo: not found`. code.exe in wsl debian starts the programme and says `Ignoring option list-extensions: not supported for code`..

Comment: @carlin, I do not understand. Why using the **command palette** or **F1**?

Comment: The trick is running `bin/code` (Linux, shell script) and `bin/code.cmd` (Windows, batch file). This is a subfolder of your `vscode` install directory. It runs electron as node and executes a cli javascript file.

Comment: `code --list-extensions` still works on VSCode, 1.74.2 at DEC 22, thanks

Comment: This might be a really bad idea, but I was able to replace the new `extensions` directory with the old one and Visual Studio code loaded the extensions fine. Just wanted to document that in case anyone wondered.

Answer (score 76):

#### Windows (PowerShell) version of [Benny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35773299/how-can-you-export-the-visual-studio-code-extension-list/49398449#49398449)

Machine A:

In the Visual Studio Code PowerShell terminal:

`code --list-extensions > extensions.list`

Machine B:

1. Copy extension.list to the machine B
2. In the Visual Studio Code PowerShell terminal:

   ```
    cat extensions.list |% { code --install-extension $_}
   ```

Comment: This just launches a new code window with the Welcome tab for me.

Comment: This answer works perfectly for me -- I had no issues at all getting everything installed.

Comment: This is my preferred answer, because it doesn't rely on xargs (compared with the higher rated answer). Now if only "code" were recognized as a command ... *sigh* (it's always something)

Comment: This worked perfectly in creating my .list file and showing me what extensions I currently have rocking. I just needed the list as a reference.  Didn't need to do the copy process. Many thanks.

Comment: Simple, low effort and effective. This should be the answer.

Comment: On Windows, run `code.cmd` instead of `code` if you are getting a new window. `code.cmd` is in the `bin/` subdirectory of your vscode install folder. On Linux, run `bin/code` (which is a shell script)

Answer (score 63):

I have developed an extension which will synchronise your all Visual Studio Code settings across multiple instances.

**Key Features**

1. Use your GitHub account token.
2. Easy to upload and download on one click.
3. Saves all settings and snippets files.
4. Upload key: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>
5. Download key: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>
6. Type Sync In Order to View all sync options

**It synchronises the**

1. Settings file
2. Keybinding file
3. Launch file
4. Snippets folder
5. Visual Studio Code **extensions**

**Detail Documentation Source**

[Visual Studio Code Sync ReadMe](http://shanalikhan.github.io/2015/12/15/Visual-Studio-Code-Sync-Settings.html)

**Download here: [Visual Studio Code Settings Sync](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/Shan.code-settings-sync)**

Comment: does this automatically installs synced extensions?

Comment: Yes! Try that and let me know

Comment: what exception you are getting in the developer console ? open a github issue in the repo and we will see

Comment: Hey, i used your extension, it is great, but i dont know how to share my extensions list with my friend.

Comment: @vanduc1102 - Check this link : http://shanalikhan.github.io/2016/09/02/how-to-Share-visual-studio-code-settings.html

Comment: It showed the message ` Delete your private GIST and create a public GIST? ` It would be nice if it will create a public GIST everytime i use the feature and keep my private GIST all the time. thanks @ShanKhan , great work

Comment: It will not delete the gist from github but only from the extension and create the public gist so when ever you need to configure the private gist you can just add the ID and sync again. Thanks for the suggest i will change this text in the menu.

Answer (score 37):

For Linux

On the *old* machine:

```
code --list-extensions > vscode-extensions.list
```

On the *new* machine:

```
cat vscode-extensions.list | xargs -L 1 code --install-extension
```

---

For Windows:

On the *old* machine:

```
code --list-extensions > vscode-extensions.list
```

On the *new* machine:

```
Get-Content vscode-extensions.list | ForEach-Object { code --install-extension $_ }
```

Comment: `cat: vscode-extensions.list: No such file or directory`

Comment: It seems you can improve your answer by specifying that the `vscode-extensions.list` file must be copied from the old machine to the new machine.

Comment: How to I export the extension list, on wsl or wsl2? I am using Vscode with remote-wsl to alpine and ubuntu

Answer (score 31):

I used the following command to copy my extensions from Visual Studio Code to Visual Studio Code insiders:

```
code --list-extensions | xargs -L 1 code-insiders --install-extension
```

The argument `-L 1` allows us to execute the command `code-insiders --install-extension` once for each input line generated by `code --list-extensions`.

Comment: This is very useful for the `init.sh` in my dotfiles repo. I first install extensions from a file and then write all currently installed extensions to the file. Only downside is I would have to delete the file if I want to remove an extension but it should work if I add one.

Answer (score 25):

If using bash, you can use the following commands:

**Export extensions**

```bash
code --list-extensions |
xargs -L 1 echo code --install-extension |
sed "s/$/ --force/" |
sed "\$!s/$/ \&/" > install-extensions.bash
```

With bash alias, just run `eve`:

```bash
# eve - export vscode extensions
alias eve='code --list-extensions |
xargs -L 1 echo code --install-extension |
sed "s/$/ --force/" |
sed "\$!s/$/ \&/" > install-extensions.bash'
```

**Install extensions**

```bash
. install-extensions.bash
```

Comment: command must be run from VSCODE  terminal -- for extended $PATH that includes code command

Comment: @Du. I was trying to replicate vscode extensions between  remote machines -- Remote SSH from Mac with updated VSCODE -- your solution is very stright and usefull

Answer (score 16):

Dump extensions:

```
code --list-extensions > extensions.txt
```

Install extensions with Bash (Linux, OS X and WSL):

```
cat extensions.txt | xargs code --list-extensions {}
```

Install extensions on Windows with PowerShell:

```
cat extensions.txt |% { code --install-extension $_}
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work. It uses `--list-extensions`, which doesn't install, so it should be something line `--install-extension` but when changed to that it still doesn't work

Comment: On Mac, not working even with "--install-extension".

Answer (score 15):

> https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_workspace-recommended-extensions

A better way to share extension list is to create workspace-based extension set for your colleagues.

After generating a list of extensions via `code --list-extensions | xargs -L 1 echo code --install-extension` (check your `$PATH` contains Visual Studio Code entry `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\` before running code commands), run `Extensions: Configure Recommended Extensions (Workspace Folder)` Visual Studio Code command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>) and put extensions into the generated `.vscode/extensions.json` file:

```
{
    "recommendations": [
        "eg2.tslint",
        "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
        "msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome"
    ]
}
```

Comment: This should've been the accepted answer...

Answer (score 12):

Generate a Windows command file (batch) for installing extensions:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %i in ('code --list-extensions')
   do @echo call code --install-extension %i >> install.cmd
```

Answer (score 9):

Open the Visual Studio Code console and write:

`code --list-extensions` (or `code-insiders --list-extensions` if Visual Studio Code insider is installed)

Then share the command line with colleagues:

`code --install-extension {ext1} --install-extension {ext2} --install-extension {extN}` replacing `{ext1}`, `{ext2}`, ... , `{extN}` with the extension you listed

For Visual Studio Code insider: `code-insiders --install-extension {ext1} ...`

If they copy/paste it in Visual Studio Code command-line terminal, they'll install the shared extensions.

More information on [command-line-extension-management](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_command-line-extension-management).

Answer (score 9):

Use Visual Studio Code's [Profiles feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles) (introduced February 2023) to share settings, including installed extensions, with colleagues using a named Profile.

### From VS Code:

1. Invoke the command: **Profiles: Export Profile**
2. In the Profiles view, review the Settings, UI State and Extensions:

[image]

3. From the Profiles view, click the **Export** button
4. Enter a name for the profile - if prompted
5. Select the `GitHub gist` save option
6. Once saved, you will see the following:

[image]

7. Press the **Copy Link** button to save the URL

### In the Browser:

1. Visit the [GitHub gist site](https://gist.github.com/) where you should see a new Gist with your profile name:
2. Select the new Gist and click the '**Edit**' button
3. In edit-mode, press the '**Make Public**' button

### Share and Import:

1. Share the URL you copied earlier with colleagues who can use the Profiles: Import Profile command.
2. The imported Profiles is associated with the current workspaces.
3. Profiles can later be switched, renamed etc. from within VS Code

Answer (score 7):

How to export your Visual Studio Code extensions from the terminal. Here is git for that. Maybe this helps somebody.

## How to export your Visual Studio Code extensions from the terminal

***Note:** [Unix-like systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system#Unix_and_Unix-like_operating_systems) only.*

1. Export your extensions to a shell file:

```sh
code --list-extensions | sed -e 's/^/code --install-extension /' > my_vscode_extensions.sh
```

2. Verify your extensions installer file:

```sh
less my_vscode_extesions.sh
```

#### Install your extensions (optional)

Run your `my_vscode_extensions.sh` using a [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) command:

```sh
bash my_vscode_extensions.sh
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"Here is git for that."*?

Answer (score 6):

#### How to share VS Code extensions without using plugins, gists, sharing files or forcing users to use a multi-line command

If you need to send all your extensions to install on another computer, you can install multiple extensions with a **single-line command** in this format:

```
code --install-extension dakshmiglani.hex-to-rgba --install-extension techer.open-in-browser
```

#### How to create the single-line command:

**1.** In your terminal, run the following command:

```
code --list-extensions
```

**2.** Copy your list of extensions from the terminal and paste your copied list into a new document.
[image: Do a regex search and replace in VS Code to share extensions on new computer]

**3.** Open a *Search and Replace* prompt (`CTRL+R` on Windows) and do a REGEX search for:

```
(.+)(\n?)
```

**4.** Replace with

```
 --install-extension $1
```

(Don't omit the space at the beginning.)

**5.** Add the word `code` to the beginning of the resulting text and you'll have a very large command that you can hand off to your colleagues to run in their terminal.

`code --install-extension hbenl.vscode-test-explorer --install-extension maciejdems.add-to-gitignore --install-extension techer.open-in-browser --install-extension traBpUkciP.vscode-npm-scripts` ...

Answer (score 4):

There is an [Extension Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=webstp.extension-manager) extension, that may help. It seems to allow to install a set of extensions specified in the `settings.json`.

Comment: I tried it but that plugin won't install jshint that I tried to add to my settings file...

Answer (score 4):

[Benny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49398449/13508) on Windows with the Linux subsystem:

```
code --list-extensions | wsl xargs -L 1 echo code --install-extension
```

Answer (score 4):

1. `code --list-extensions > list`
2. `sed -i 's/.*/\"&\",/' list`
3. Copy contents of file `list` and add to file `.vscode/extensions.json` in the `"recommendations"`  section.
4. If `extensions.json` doesn't exist then create a file with the following contents

   ```
   {
       "recommendations": [
           // Add content of file list here
       ]
   }
   ```
5. Share the `extensions.json` file and ask another user to add to the `.vscode` folder. Visual Studio Code will prompt for installation of extensions.

Answer (score 4):

Now there's a feature still in preview that allows you to sign in with a Microsoft or GitHub account and have your settings synced without any additional extension. It's pretty simple and straigh-forward. You can learn more [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync).

[The things you can sync.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1a25.png)

Answer (score 3):

I opened the Visual Studio Code extensions folder and executed:

```
find * -maxdepth 2 -name "package.json" | xargs grep "name"
```

That gives you a list from which you can extract the extension names.

Answer (score 3):

Under windows typically I need to run

```
cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin
code.cmd --list-extensions
```

What you don't do is run the code.exe directly under C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\

Comment: **vscode** is not installed in `program files` nor in `program files (x86)`

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to share workspace extensions configuration across a team, you should look into the [Recommended Extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_workspace-recommended-extensions) feature of Visual Studio Code.

To generate this file, open the command pallet > `Configure Recommended Extensions (Workspace Folder)`. From there, if you wanted to get all of your current extensions and put them in here, you could use the `--list-extensions` stuff mentioned in other answers, but add some AWK script to make it paste-able into a JSON array (you can get more or less advanced with this as you please - this is just a quick example):

`code --list-extensions | awk '{ print "\""$0"\"\,"}'`

The advantage of this method is that your team-wide workspace configuration can be checked into source control. With this file present in a project, when the project is opened Visual Studio Code will notify the user that there are recommended extensions to install (if they don't already have them) and can install them all with a single button press.

Answer (score 2):

For those that are wondering how to copy your extensions from Visual Studio Code to Visual Studio Code insiders, use this modification of [Benny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35773299/how-can-you-export-the-visual-studio-code-extension-list/49398449#49398449):

```
code --list-extensions | xargs -L 1 echo code-insiders --install-extension
```

Answer (score 2):

On Windows using PowerShell script, including a 'friendlyName' which better matches the extension name as it appears in Visual Studio Code interface (which `code --list-extensions` doesn't do):

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Gets installed Visual Studio Code extensions in a friendly format.

.DESCRIPTION
    Gets installed Visual Studio Code extensions in a friendly format.

.INPUTS
    None. You cannot pipe objects to this.

.OUTPUTS
    Installed Visual Studio Code extensions in a friendly format.

.EXAMPLE
    PS> .\Get-VSCodeExtensions.ps1

.NOTES
    Authors: John Bentley, Andrew D. Bond <https://github.com/andrewdbond/>

    Updated: 2023-03-22

    Latest:
    How can you export the Visual Studio Code extension list?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72929878/872154
#>

$extensions = (Get-Item $HOME/.vscode/extensions/*/package.json).ForEach({
    Get-Content $_ | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object `
        @{name='friendlyName';expr={if($_.PSObject.Properties['displayName']) {$_.displayName} else { $_.name}}},
        @{name='publisherAndName';expr={"$($_.publisher).$($_.name)"}},
        description,
        homepage,
        @{name='repository.url';expr={$_.repository.url}},
        version
}) | Sort-Object friendlyName

Write-Output $extensions
# Optional: Set clipboard with the results to paste into Google Sheets, Excel, etc.
$extensions | ConvertTo-Csv | Set-Clipboard
```

Example output:

```
friendlyName     : Pylance
publisherAndName : ms-python.vscode-pylance
description      : A performant, feature-rich language server for Python in VS Code
homepage         : 
repository.url   : https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release
version          : 2023.3.20

friendlyName     : Python
publisherAndName : ms-python.python
description      : IntelliSense (Pylance), Linting, Debugging (multi-threaded, remote), Jupyter Notebooks, code formatting,  
                   refactoring, unit tests, and more.
homepage         : https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python
repository.url   : https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python
version          : 2023.4.1
```

Instructions (Windows only):

1. Paste the above script code into a PowerShell terminal

Or

1. Copy the above script code and save it somewhere as `Get-VSCodeExtensions.ps1`
2. Open a PowerShell terminal at the directory where you saved `Get-VSCodeExtensions.ps1` (`cd` might help here)
3. Run the script from the PowerShell terminal with `.\Get-VSCodeExtensions.ps1`

Comment: Below `PublisherAndName = ...` I put `Description = $json.description` to get the text description in the output as well.

Comment: @NathanGoings good idea. Your suggestion probably helps when sharing such a list with other devs to communicate 'this is what I use, pick from it what you like'. I edited in your line to the code. It will be easy for a dev to delete it, if it doesn't suit their tastes.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to transfer all the extensions from `code` to `code-insiders` or vice versa, here is what worked for me from [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway).

```
code --list-extensions | xargs -L 1 code-insiders --install-extension
```

This will install all the missing extensions and skip the installed ones. After that, you will need to close and reopen Visual Studio Code.

Similarly, you can transfer extensions from `code-insiders` to `code` with the following:

```
code-insiders --list-extensions | xargs -L 1 code --install-extension
```

Answer (score 1):

> <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Turn on Settings Sync</kbd>  Will sync your `VS Code` settings across different devices.

I'm using VS Code Version **1.74.0**

Comment: No can do. I cannot use my account on other dev's stations.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux/Mac only, export the installed Visual Studio Code extensions in the form of an installation script. It's a Z shell (Zsh) script, but it may run in Bash as well.

https://gist.github.com/jvlad/6c92178bbfd1906b7d83c69780ee4630

Comment: This is actually good, why the negative vote?

Answer (score 0):

I create an extension for this problem.
This extension allows you to export a list of all currently installed extensions in your Visual Studio Code. The exported list is saved in a JSON file that can be imported later to restore the extensions.

[How can you export the Visual Studio Code extension list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35773299/how-can-you-export-the-visual-studio-code-extension-list)

(Ctrl+Shift+P or Cmd+Shift+P) and type

`Export Extensions`

`Import Extensions`

Answer (score 0):

This method uses helps install existing extensions on a new system (with reference to an existing system) **`using .vsix package`**

It requires Yeoman VS Code [extension generator](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension) and [vsce](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#vsce) (or [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) to install these).

1. On the existing machine, generate an `extension pack` (more details [here](https://xingzhi.dev/blog/multiple-extensions-vscode#2-expansion-pack))

> ```
> npm install -g yo generator-code
>
> yo code
> ```

First command installs Yeoman VS Code generator, second creates the extension pack (choose default options as below. The created `package.json` contains all extensions in the pack, you can modify that list)

[image]

[image]

[image]

2. On the existing machine, package the extension pack created above into a `.vsix file`

> ```
> npm install -g vsce
>  
> vsce package
> ```

First command installs vsce, second packages the extension into a `.vsix file` (run from the root of the extension pack created above)

[image]

3. On the new system, install the `.vsix file`

> ```
> code --install-extension extension-pack-0.0.1.vsix
> ```

4. Open VS Code on the new system, access this extension, install all required extensions via GUI

[image]

PS: If you are going to publish the extension pack then consider filling in all details appropriately, while creating it.