# Export/Import VS extensions list?

Tags: import, export, backup, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

Is there an easy way to backup the installed extensions list in VS (2017), so that when I install the machine anew I can easily install my regular extensions at once?

Note: I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35773299/how-can-you-export-vs-code-extension-list) question that asks an identical question to my own, except it targets VS Code, whereas my question is about Visual Studio for Windows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Roaming Extension Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.RoamingExtensionManager) is built in Visual Studio 2017:

> The Roaming Extension Manager helps you keep track of all your
>   favorite extensions across all of your development environments.
>   Roaming your extensions keeps track of the extensions you have
>   installed by creating a synchronized list in the cloud.

See also https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/roaming-extension-manager-control-and-consistency-down-to-the-last-extension/

Comment: The extension in you link is for VS 2015. If this is built-in, can you please share a link to a blog or article that shows how to use it?

Comment: The github link is dead

Comment: @Jon49 I've changed the link.

Comment: @SergeyVlasov It's dead again

Comment: @NetherGranite Both links work for me. Though the second one is quite slow.

Comment: @SergeyVlasov Sorry, I forgot to specify which link. I meant the GitHub one in the comments.

Comment: It is built in to VS2019, not sure about VS 2017. The original link is a blog post that shows there's a flyout on the left of the Extensions Dialog with your extensions from "elsewhere". If they're found on the gallery, they can be downloaded.

Answer (score 8):

Re-visiting this for Visual Studio 2019, you can use this extension to import/export your extensions: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ExtensionManager2019