# How to install multiple extensions in VSCode using command line

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, command-line-interface

How can I install multiple extensions in VSCode using the cli? I tried:

```
code --install-extension xyz.local-history jock.svg
```

but it only installs the first extension `xyz.local-history`.

```
Installing extensions...
Installing extension 'xyz.local-history' v1.7.0...
(node:10874) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
Extension 'xyz.local-history' v1.7.0 was successfully installed.
```

Comment: Can you use a loop in your command line to run `code --install-extension` multiple times?

Answer (score 14):

If you are use **Unix/Linux** create a bash script with a loop. In this case I want to backup the extensions list and install again:

First create a list of the extensions:

```sh
$ code --list-extensions > extensions.txt
```

Create a bash script for example with the name `vscode-extension-install.sh` and input the following code:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cat extensions.txt | while read extension || [[ -n $extension ]];
do
  code --install-extension $extension --force
done
```

Then run:

```sh
$ ./vscode-extension-install.sh
```

Example output:

```sh
Installing extensions...
Installing extension 'visualstudioexptteam.vscodeintellicode' v1.2.6...
Extension 'visualstudioexptteam.vscodeintellicode' v1.2.6 was successfully installed.
Installing extensions...
Installing extension 'vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons' v10.0.0...
Extension 'vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons' v10.0.0 was successfully installed.
...
```

From [my gists](https://gist.github.com/illvart/bf98de24cb2facfbc332269aadd149c8)

Answer (score 6):

It's possible to pass the `--install-extension` argument multiple times and so install several extensions with just one line.

```sh
code --install-extension dbaeumer.vscode-eslint --install-extension esbenp.prettier-vscode
```

The documentation for this can be found in [Extension Marketplace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_install-from-a-vsix). Running this both extensions are installed but `Installing extensions...` is only found once in the output.

Answer (score 4):

Declare a variable, containing the name of all extensions you want to install... after you have it, you can iterate doing the installation one by one...

```js
for extensions in ms-python.python ms-azure-devops.azure-pipelines ms-mssql.mssql 
do code --install-extension $extensions
done
```

Maybe you also have to add your code.cmd path, but if your command is working typring code, this will be enough to do the taks
Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Windows and do not use WSL, try a PowerShell loop.

1. Put all desired extensions in a text file (as in Linux example above) - say `extensions.txt`
2. Iterate over them with:
   `Get-Content extensions.txt | ForEach-Object {code --install-extension $_}`

*Note: this would work on every system supporting PowerShell*

Comment: I wonder how to update the extensions to the latest version, especially extensions inside the extension pack

Comment: @Bruce: Using the same switch (`--install-extension` with a `--force` argument).

Answer (score 1):

there is actually a very simple, one-line solution for this:

```bash
$ sed -n 's/^/--install-extension /p' extension.list | xargs code
```

This will install all extensions exported with `code --list-extensions` in one call.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: This is not a command line approach, but rather a **`graphical way`** to install existing extensions on a new system **`using .vsix package`**, and might help some others with the same.

---

This method to install extensions on a new system (with reference to an existing system) requires Yeoman VS Code [extension generator](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension) and [vsce](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#vsce) (or [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) to install these).

1. On the existing machine, generate an `extension pack` (more details [here](https://xingzhi.dev/blog/multiple-extensions-vscode#2-expansion-pack))

> ```
> npm install -g yo generator-code
>
> yo code
> ```

First command installs Yeoman VS Code generator, second creates the extension pack (choose default options as below. The created `package.json` contains all extensions in the pack, you can modify that list)

[image]

[image]

[image]

2. On the existing machine, package the extension pack created above into a `.vsix file`

> ```
> npm install -g vsce
>  
> vsce package
> ```

First command installs vsce, second packages the extension into a `.vsix file` (run from the root of the extension pack created above)

[image]

3. On the new system, install the `.vsix file`

> ```
> code --install-extension extension-pack-0.0.1.vsix
> ```

4. Open VS Code on the new system, access this extension, install all required extensions via GUI

[image]

Comment: If you are going to publish the extension pack then consider filling in all details appropriately, while creating it.

Answer (score 0):

CLI find command could support this,
in my Dockerfile, code-server could install multi vsix by find command.
I think code could use similar scenario

```
ARG user=docker
#vscode server 1.79.1
ARG vscommit=4cb974a7aed77a74c7813bdccd99ee0d04901215

ADD ./vscode_extension/*.vsix /home/${user}/vscode_extension/
# install vscode extension
RUN find ./ -name '*vsix' -exec  ~/.vscode-server/bin/${vscommit}/bin/code-server --accept-server-license-terms--install-extension {} \;
```

Answer (score -1):

Might be useful to others.

I keep a dump of all extensions in text file for example:

```
code --install-extension aaron-bond.better-comments
code --install-extension abusaidm.html-snippets
code --install-extension afractal.node-essentials
code --install-extension anseki.vscode-color
code --install-extension be5invis.vscode-icontheme-nomo-dark
....
```

I would copy all contents of text file and then paste all the contents to PowerShell and then it would install plugins one by one.