# Copy enable/disable extensions settings to another workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code

**Idea:**

I wanted to clean up my vscode extensions, because I'm working with a lot of different languages/file types and having all these extensions installed and enabled at once is just too much.

**Problem:**

I disabled some extensions for a specific workspace, and wanted to copy these settings to another workspace, but vscode is not storing the information about enabled/disabled extensions in `.vscode/settings.json`.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any way to copy these settings from one workspace to another?
2. Is there a better way of dealing with lots of extensions?
3. Can you recommend tools/extensions for managing extensions per workspace or language(s)

> I assume vscode is not loading all extensions at once, but rather when needed. But some extensions display icons on the left or bottom of the window and overcrowd the "Show All Commands" list/search.

Answer (score 9):

VS Code stores this info in its *internals* instead of the `.vscode` folder, so you can't *copy* this info between workspaces. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/40239) asking exactly what you want.

But, you have an alternative. Use the [Profile Switcher](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aaronpowell.vscode-profile-switcher) extension.

Its description:

> This extension allows you to define a number of settings profiles that you can easily switch between. The original idea for this extension came from my desire to have an easy way for me to switch my VS Code to a setup that was better optimised for presenting (changed themes, increase font size, etc).

And this is how it handles extensions:

> A profile isn't just the settings you have enabled, but also the extensions that were installed. This allows you to create different profiles for different styles of development (e.g. a React profile and a Vue profile, loading their respective extensions only).

Hope this helps

Comment: Hey, thank you, I'll checkout the extension as soon as I can and let you know if it works for me! And the issue/feature request looks good too!

Comment: Ok so the Profile Switcher extension is not what I want or would recommend. It uninstalls extensions rather than disabling them, and did mess with my settings. So I'll keep searching for a solution.

Comment: It uninstalls (but makes a backup first) those that you don’t want in your “profile”. If you want some extension to be always available, use the `extensionsIgnore` setting.

Comment: I agree this may not be _ the best approach_, but it seems to work well, and is the only extension available, for now...

Comment: Uninstalling extensions is not going to work for me, because I'm working with multiple instances of vscode in different projects that are connected, so I need all extensions to be installed! That's why I want to be able to copy the enabled/disabled extension settings and since vscode is storing them somewhere it has to be possible to copy them! Yes maybe there is no extension that does this yet, but if I would know where to find these settings and how to distinguish between the different workspaces I could work with that!

Comment: I’m not sure, but if I remember correctly, the “other instances” are not notified when you install/uninstall extensions (in normal VS Code scenarios). I’m not sure how that extension handles it. About the “internals”, VS Code is based on Electron, which uses Chromium. Until last year, its “internals” where the LocalStorage available in Chromium, but they changed it to store “on disk” (a SQLite file, I guess) each workspace separately . You could try to access that files, but I think is “too much”. You will probably have to wait for that issue to be closed.

Comment: I don't maybe the "other instances" would no get notified, but if you have to reload the instance because of some bug or what ever reason it would get the information that something changed... so that doesn't seem link an option to me... I'll see what I can do with the `workspaceStorage` which is located next to the `settings.json` https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations

Answer (score 1):

There is a github issue for this problem: [Feature Request: Enable/disable extensions from config file #40239](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/40239).

I posted there a workaround using multiple vscode instances: [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/40239#issuecomment-582671616)

Here is a copy-paste:

---

I use some kind of workaround to be able to use the extensions I want.

According to the vscode-cli your can specify the folders for extensions and user-data:

```sh
Options                  Description

--extensions-dir <dir>   Set the root path for extensions.
--user-data-dir <dir>    Specifies the directory that user data is kept in. Can be used to open multiple distinct instances of Code.
```

Basically, I create a specific folder for my specific tasks (one of front, one for back, ..) and set basic extensions to my default vscode.

To launch my custom config:

```sh
code --extensions-dir "$HOME/.vscode/profiles/my-super-profile/extensions" --user-data-dir "$HOME/.vscode/profiles/my-super-profile/data"
```

The problem are that:

- It's not REALLY a project config file but a global preference file
- I had to install manually the extensions. I believe there is a hackish way to do this
- It use more size than necessary (multiple vscode data / duplicate extensions)
- It doesn't solve in a clean way the team-sharing problem

Comment: Hey thanks for this I'll give it a try soon! But for now it sounds good to me, for installing the extensions I can create scripts and size doesn't matter, it may not be the cleanest way of doing this but it sounds like it would do what I want (for now) and really keep things separated, also when using different directories its less likely to mess up my settings!

Answer (score 1):

**VS Code Extension:** [Unwanted Recommendations](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GARAIOAG.garaio-vscode-unwanted-recommendations) made possible by GARAIO LABS [[ref]](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/40239#issuecomment-1375910194)

---

As of 2023-March, the extension:

- Allows specifying extensions that are unwanted in `extensions.json`

  ```
  {
    "recommendations": [
      "vue.volar"
    ],
    "unwantedRecommendations": [
      "vscode.typescript-language-features",
      "octref.vetur",
      "vue.vscode-typescript-vue-plugin"
    ]
  }
  ```
- On VS Code workspace open, will prompt to disable unwanted extensions in workspace (if any found not yet disabled)
- User then MANUALLY selects extension from the filtered list and sets it to `Disabled (in workspace)`

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is with `profiles`, as noted [here](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/vscode-export-settings-and-extensions):

1. In the Command Palette (`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P`), type `Profiles: Export Profile...`
2. Select the items you want to export
3. Create a name for the profile
4. Choose whether to save it to a `Local file` or `GitHub gist`

I store mine in `.vscode/` in my repo for each project and push that to GitHub. Then I tell users/contributors to import the profile using `Profiles: Import Profile...` in the Command Palette.

**NOTE:** *These commands are (now) built into VSCode by default and [ProfileSwitcher is deprecated](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aaronpowell.vscode-profile-switcher).*