# What are ALL configuration files used by Visual Studio Code, and where does it store memory of what notifications to not show again?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code from what I know handles **User** and **Workspace** configurations in `JSON` format.
It creates `.vscode` folder in the *working directory* (when necessary) and another in *user home* (e.g. used to store marketplace extensions).

I'm wondering if there's also another place.

For example, if you create a file without using New File button, e.g. from terminal:

```
echo "dummy" >dummy.abc
```

And then you open it in the editor, you will be prompted with a dialog like this:

[image: VS Code marketplace dialog]

If you hit **Don't Show Again...** and repeat the same experiment in the same directory or in another, VS Code will remember it (it will not present the dialog a second time).

I know it's not an important thing... But I want to know where this is stored.

So, are there any other config file that VS Code uses?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have `default settings`, `user settings`, `workspace settings`, `single folder settings` (legacy) and `repository settings`.

You can access your `defaultSettings.json` by typing "default settings" in the command palette (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> in Windows/Linux).

You can access your user settings.json file by pressing `Cmd+,` (or `Ctrl+,` in Windows/Linux).

The workspace settings go inside a `.code-workspace` file in the
   "settings" key, like so:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "breadcrumbs.enabled": true // Settings here
    }
}
```

The single-folder settings go into the `/.vscode/settings.json` file. The single-folder state is a legacy feature. You can insert both repository-wide and workspace-wide settings inside the /.vscode/settings.json file when in a single-folder state but workspace settings stop working if you turn that into a workspace. This can be confusing because VS Code creates an implicit/unsaved workspace if you choose the "`Remove folder from Workspace`" or the "`Add folder to workspace`" options in your file explorer.
[image]

The repository settings go into the `/.vscode/settings.json` file.

[I've recorded a video on where settings are applied](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rPl4XcGq4Mg&list=PLVwLx67OHLu0mEz51BK0B89MZ9HG-6hpi&index=8) that contains a slight misconception, which I'm hoping to correct soon, around the single-folder legacy functionality that I was not aware of at the time of the recording. I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 31):

The VS Code docs mention the [location for the settings files](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations):

> Depending on your platform, the user settings file is located here:
>
> - Windows `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`
> - macOS `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`
> - Linux `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`

If you take a look at the `Code` folder, there are a bunch of other files stored there:

```
Code$ tree -L 1
.
├── Backups
├── Cache
├── CachedData
├── CachedExtensions
├── Code\ Cache
├── Cookies
├── Cookies-journal
├── GPUCache
├── Local\ Storage
├── Network\ Persistent\ State
├── Preferences
├── User
├── Workspaces
├── blob_storage
├── languagepacks.json
├── logs
├── machineid
├── rapid_render.json
├── storage.json
└── webrtc_event_logs
```

Those contain all the settings/configurations that VS Code maintains (apart from the *.vscode* folder in your workspace). If you delete the *Code* folder, your VS Code would then behave like it was freshly installed.

Most of them aren't easily readable like JSON though, and most are stored in SQL DB files (*.vscdb*). For example, for remembering that "*Don't Show Again*" prompt for files with *.abc* extensions, it's stored in *User/globalStorage/state.vscdb*. Use a SQLite browser (like [this](https://sqlitebrowser.org/)) to open up that file, and you'll see this:

[image]

...which stores the setting to not prompt me again for *.csv* and *.abc* files. (Try removing the "abc" from the DB value, and VS Code will prompt you again.)

For workspace-specific settings, they are stored in *User/workspaceStorage*, where each workspace is organized into folders like this:

```
workspaceStorage$ tree -L 1
.
├── 145974865976a98123d05b3b96dbf2c5
├── 20159dfdb7c4cda12efaac5f8e64a954
├── 33fd12012abefa2f7f2f0a3f185999cf
├── 34a3fbd8b284b6cfb29882db362faa4e
├── 44b251d79bd7f8f49c350d022bf7d03d
├── 63d838186f19687db224f4f7a27c62ab
...
```

Go into any one, and check the *workspace.json* to know which workspace the DB file is for. Then again open the *state.vscdb* to see something like this:

[image]

...which shows settings for remembering which files are opened, etc..

Comment: Thanks, that helped me find the image-specific settings for the Remote-Containers extension: `~/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/imageConfigs`. Will be handy for automation with a multi-repo dev container scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I'm  under the impression that nobody else got your question right...

There are at least 3 different configurations files that i know of that can be transfered quickly to a new VSCode setup to reproduce all your configurations:

1. settings.json
2. keybindings.json
3. snippet.code_snippets (last one needing to be created by the user first for his own custom snippets if needed; there could be more then one of those)

On Windows, you can find them under the path:
`C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Code\User`

You can also create list your extensions by using the code CLI. There's also a CLI command to install your extensions. `code --help` will give you more info if necessary. You can also take a look at this thread: [How can you export the Visual Studio Code extension list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35773299/how-can-you-export-the-visual-studio-code-extension-list)

```
code --list-extensions > ^
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\my_extensions.md
```

Be aware that if you are using Remote SSH,  this command will give you different results depending on whether you are on your local VSCode or on a remote development workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I can prove beyond reasonable doubt that too much reliance of an IDE menu system leads to pain and suffering.

The global settings in vscode in Ubuntu is here:

```
$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Global things are in the SQLite database under `User/globalStorage/state.vscdb` in the same directory [where user settings files are stored](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations). Workspaces also have a SQL database in that directory, under `User/workspaceStorage`.

If you want to have an easier way to reset what things you have told VS Code not to show you again, see [Allow to reset “Don't Show Again” preference #24815](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/24815). Give it a thumbs up to show support for it. You can subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like "+1" / "bump".