# Is there a way to clear out the old Jupyter URIs in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

Does anyone know how to clear out the old connection strings from the list after the "Python: Specify Jupyter server URI" command is ran?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the only way to clear it is to clear your global memento cache in VS code. That's where this MRU list is stored.

See this item for where to find the global cache:
[What are ALL configuration files used by Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58900482/what-are-all-configuration-files-used-by-visual-studio-code)