# Git permission denied, but everything seems fine

Tags: git

I had no problem so far with git, but without any apparent reason I cannot do anything and it keeps me giving "permission denied".
The credentials are set, also the ssh is correct and if I do `ssh -vT git@gitlab.com` it connects without problems. But I cannot pull, commit or clone anything.
How can I solve this?

UPDATE:
This is part of the output for the ssh command

Command: `ssh -vT git@gitlab.com`

```
Authenticated to gitlab.com ([172.65.251.78]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: /authorized_keys %u %k:1: key options: command user-rc
debug1: Remote: /authorized_keys %u %k:1: key options: command user-rc
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = it_IT.UTF-8
Welcome to GitLab, @laramar!
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3616, received 3048 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 12958.6, received 10923.1
debug1: Exit status 0
```

When I do the `git clone git@gitlab.com:laramar/1972_theme_omeka.git`:

```
remote: 
remote: ========================================================================
remote: 
remote: The namespace you were looking for could not be found.
remote: 
remote: ========================================================================
remote: 
fatal: Impossibile leggere dal repository remoto.

Assicurati di disporre dei privilegi d'accesso corretti
e che il repository esista.
```

Plus, I got some strange folders in my home. Like "GPUCache" or "Local storage". They are all like that

[image]

and they appeared from nowhere...

Comment: Can you provide more details such as what output you receive for the ssh command as well as the clone/pull command?

Comment: Updated the question, thank you

Comment: Can you include the command you used (redacted as necessary)? If it's a public repo, can you include a browser access link to the project?

Comment: That's the repo: https://gitlab.com/laramar/1972_theme_omeka

Comment: The folders don't seem to be related. I googled some of their names and found threads talking about bugs in PDF software like Adobe Reader and Nitro.

Comment: No, I think it's related because they appear everywhere I use git commands

Comment: HTTPS clone worked for me (`git clone https://gitlab.com/laramar/1972_theme_omeka.git`), so I bet this problem is specific to GitLab's SSH. I don't have a GitLab SSH account to check.

Comment: @LaraM. But git doesn't use the GPU...

Comment: Ok, it works fine with HTTPS

Answer (score 1):

VS Code employs caching and storage to restore state and provide a faster experience, with the [full tree displayed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58905720/6309).

Your SSH URL should have worked (see also [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58905720/6309))
But if SSH fails (for instance, if it is not usable, in a corporate environment setting), switch to HTTPS.