# Which file(s) contain the UI State details

Tags: visual-studio-code

Currently I save `keybindings.json`, `settings.json`, `~/.vscode/extensions`, `~/.config/Code/User/snippets` and `~/.config/VSCodium/User/globalStorage/alefragnani.project-manager/projects.json` in my dotfiles to backup vscode.

The [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync) says:

```
Following UI State is synchronized currently:

 - Display Language
 - Activity Bar entries
 - Panel entries
 - Views layout and visibility
 - Recently used commands
 - Do not show again notifications
```

Which file(s) shall I backup if I want to backup the **UI State** in my dotfiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP Here. The file that contain the UI State seems to be `~/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/state.vscdb`. I have added this to my dotfiles as well.

For more details please check [What are ALL configuration files used by Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58905720/1772898)