# Where are the settings for the VSCode snippet feature stored?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

Normally, whenever you make a settings-related change in VSCode, it adds a line to your "settings.json" file, which is located by default at:

```
C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json
```

However, when I perform the following steps:

Ctrl + Shift + P --> Insert Snippet --> Search for "log" --> Click on the eye

This disables the snippet for "console.log". However, it does not make any changes to my "settings.json" file.

After poking around in the Code profile directory, it seems like there are two snippet related directories:

```
C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\snippets
C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\sync\snippets
```

However, there aren't any changes to these directories either, which leaves me stumped as to where the eye-related-changed could be stored.

1. Where is this information for snippets stored?
2. And how would I disable the console.log snippet on a per-workspace level like I would with a ruler or any other VSCode setting?

For reference, the relevant source code seems to be located here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/8feb40b9284c339e2d1b0a493641e603b7f84d3d/src/vs/workbench/contrib/snippets/browser/snippetsService.ts#L165

But having the source code isn't very helpful here, as I am not really familiar with the VSCode codebase.

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer question 1 and I don't know how helpful the answer will be.

When I set the `log warn` snippet to ignore I found this line

```
snippets.ignoredSnippets["snippets/javascript.code-snippets/Log warning to console"]
```

in this file

```
C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\state.vscdb
```

For viewing that type of file and other good information about workspace state see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58905720/836330.

Maybe you can copy that `snippets.ignoredSnippets` entry into the workspace level storage located at

```
C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage
```

and then the latest folder/state.vscdb ?  My guess is that you can only ignore snippets on a global (user) basis and not per workspace.