# Why does Visual Studio Code keep things (like settings and recently opened files) after reinstalling and how to reset everything?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to reset Visual Studio Code on my Laptop **entirely** and already uninstalled everything, even deleted the .vscode file unter the user file. But after reinstalling, everything is the same as before. The settings are exactly the same and also my recently opened files are shown.

I don't want to reset everything individually and manually, I want the *whole* program to be new. Where is all that information saved, and how can I delete it?

Comment: Are you signed in? Are you syncing changes to your account (maybe using github)?

Comment: No, I never signed in... the sync is turned off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pretty common thing for uninstaller programs to purposely leave behind configuration files (and sadly, even cache files if the uninstaller is lazily implemented <sup><sub>(or maybe even that's by-design- who knows)</sub></sup>).

For VS Code, see (on specific platforms):

- Windows: `%APPDATA%\Code`
- macOS: `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code`
- Linux: `$HOME/.config/Code`

Those folders store things like cache data, user settings, workspace info database files, etc. (Related: [What are ALL configuration files used by Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58900482/11107541))

See also `.vscode` in your user home folder for storage of extensions.

Answer (score 2):

To completely reset vsCode you also have to delete the data from your computer. Go to `AppData\Roaming\Code` and delete the folder.