# Where are Visual Studio Code extension settings to be stored?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Where are Visual Studio Code extension settings stored on Linux? Are they co-mingled with the base Visual Studio Code (User/Workspace/workFolder) settings files, or put in separate sections of these JSON files, or in their extension specific files?

Where is this documented?

Comment: If I am correct, the settings for VSCode on Linux should be stored in a `settings.json` file. `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json` may be a place to look.

Comment: 1. VS Code settings span over multiple levels (machine/user/project) and multiple files. 2. An extension author defines what the settings are and then allows the end users to set the values anywhere they like. So, do you want to learn the exact file locations for 1, or where to define settings in 2?

Comment: @LexLi Do you happen to know some locations on Linux for the multiple levels that you talk about (specifically machine & user)?

Comment: @BillJoe you can take a look at [What are ALL configuration files used by Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58900482/what-are-all-configuration-files-used-by-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings for extensions are found in the user and workspace settings JSON file. You can add custom extension settings there, you’ll just have to check the specific extension page to see what the options are per extension.

```
Ctrl+Shift+X > Extensions > Installed > SPECIFIC-EXTENSION > Feature Contributions > Settings
```

See [User and Workspace Settings - Extension settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_extension-settings)

Comment: It answers the exact question what are you talking about?