# Where does VS Code store some of its settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

There are some (to me) "magical" settings which VS Code stores in places unknown to me (speak, not in the project folder). To understand VS Code better, I would like to know where these places are. I am on Linux.

For example, the debug panel. When I click the blue "run and debug" button the first time, I get the pop-up which lets me choose the debug configuration. From now on, when clicking that button, VS Code will not show this pop up anymore, but choose the configuration I selected the first time (which is not cool). Where is this information stored?

Another example is the dialog which asks me if this folder can be trusted. This will also just ask the first time. Where is this information stored?

---

Edit: SO has automatically added a few useful questions at the bottom, for example:

- [Where does VS Code store its memory of what notifications I've previously requested to not be given again in the future?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58900482/where-does-vs-code-store-its-memory-of-what-notifications-ive-previously-reques?rq=2)
- [How to reset settings in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108515/how-to-reset-settings-in-visual-studio-code?rq=2)

So I am voting to close my question, Thanks to the commenters.

---

Edit 2:

I figured out that deleting the folders under `~/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage` lets VS Code forget that I clicked the blue "run and debug" button.<sup>1</sup>

Deleting also the `state.vscdb`, `state.vscdb.backup`, and `storage.json` under `~/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/` lets VS Code forget that it asked if a folder is trusted. A few other things will also be forgotten, e.g., which files were opened, which plugins were disabled, etc.

<sup>1</sup> Of course, VS Code should not remember this at all. That is what the "create launch.json file"-link below the button is for (avoid choosing the debug configuration). And it can be undone by deleting the launch.json. But the weird behavior of the button can not simply be undone. New users experimenting with it will curse (as I did) because the drop-down is suddenly gone.

Comment: search in the VSC directory nearby where it stores the user settings and keybindings for `*.db` files, they store workspace information

Comment: The debug configuration should be in `.vscode/launch.json` in the project directory.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat VS Code does not create this file when I just click the "run and debug" button, but it will when I click the link below the button, "create a launch.json file".

Comment: Thanks @rioV8, I guess with "VSC directory", you mean in this case `~/.config/Code/`, [as pointed out here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58905720/1658543).

Comment: Open the User `settings.json` file and examine the location, it is different for all OS

Comment: @rioV8 Good one. Indeed, the search entry at the top shows the location.