# Proper way to import a Flask VSCODE project from a friend into my VSCODE?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, flask

I am attempting to import/run a Flask project given to me by a friend.  I received a zipped up directory of the entire VSCode project.

How do I properly import a project from my friend into my computer and run it?

It seems like I am missing settings/extensions/etc. but I don't know where to start to resolve this.

Can someone point me to a set of instructions to aid me in getting my VSCODE in sync with my friend's vscode, so that I have all requirements loaded/proper extensions, etc.?

When I open the folder in VSCODE, I cannot run the project and it's not giving me much to go on.

Comment: [What research have you done?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) How has that research failed you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you export the Visual Studio Code extension list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35773299/how-can-you-export-the-visual-studio-code-extension-list)

Comment: Not really, I have the list of extensions but I've spent most of the day trying to get it to run to no avail.  There are around 20+ things in the requirements.txt file .  However, it seems like the project outputs show me it's missing multiple components such as flask, flask sqlalchemy and others, but these directories exist in the project.  So there is some disconnect between what is present in the project folder and what VSCODE and python believes that's there.

Comment: The project folder does not necessarily contain VS Extensions, you will need to install those. The linked SO Question has several methods for synching extensions and settings.

Comment: Let me clarify.  The main issue that I am having is that I don't think the project is "seeing" that the various modules here: SocialApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages are installed/available.  For example, I am getting 3 errors on various "IMPORTS" inside the root app.py.   These modules do exist in the "site-packages" folder above, but when I try to run the project, the project has no idea these are present.  So there must be a proper way for me to handle this...

Comment: Here are three that it's not finding, but are present in site-packages:  from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash